# Strange effect on rounded image [imageloader lib]

Tags: android, xml, universal-image-loader

I have this issue using the library

[image]

**My application class**

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).discCacheExtraOptions(1200, 800, CompressFormat.PNG, 75,null).build();
ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

**My Activity**

```
ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(10))
.cacheInMemory(false)
.cacheOnDisc(false)
.build();

ImageLoader.getInstance()
.displayImage("http://bucket3.clanacion.com.ar/anexos/fotos/45/mundial-brasil-2014-1897745w620.jpg", imageView1,options);
```

**My xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_blanco"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="2dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**My border_blanco drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="@color/azul" />

    <corners android:radius="10dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/verde" />

</shape>
```

Thanks!

[Issue in github](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/issues/652)

Comment: Have you tried?
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp" />

Comment: yes, the image is not displayed :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version you are using ?  Update to 1.9.2 helped